# Explanation needed: How to extract link from one-click hosters(Megaupload,rapidshare etc)

Tags: file, download, theory

I am creating a download manager for educational purpose. I intend to implement a kind of system that downloads from one-click hosters just like jdownloader or cryptload.

What are the processes/methods involved in extracting the exact download link from the host site? I know this methods may differ from each hosters.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for jDownloader available for everyone so if you have Subversion you can look at it and maybe you'll find how it works.

[link](http://svn.jdownloader.org/projects/show/jd)

Answer (score 0):

find the value of the href attribute of the a tag that is wrapping the image caption Regular Download

you could use simple_html_dom to parse it

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($pageHTML);
$x = $html->find('a[class=down_butt1]')
$exact = $x->href;
```

Comment: but megaupload is DOWN starting today